# Replacement lens for camera module

Tags: camera

I have been trying to find a better lens to use on the camera module. Specifically, I would like to use it as a security camera, and wish to be able to focus the image to around 6-10 meters. At the moment, the image seems slightly fuzzy.

I have tinkered with cracking the glue seal and twisting the existing lens, but this doesn't improve the sharpness of the image. I have also used the software controls within UV4L streaming server which help fake a slightly sharper image.

There are so many options on Amazon / eBay so I would like a little guidance if possible please.

To try and keep this question within the guidelines, I am asking for a replacement lens (or mount & lens assembly) with the ability to focus the image to a point around 6-10 meters away. Ideally, this would be available from a UK source.

Comment: maybe this http://www.truetex.com/raspberrypi would be useful?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it still is asking for a shoping recommendation which are off-topic per site rules.